# Issue with Javascript window.location redirecting

Tags: javascript, firebase, redirect, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have an app which is written in HTML, CSS, Javascript. I am able to login using Google Authentication. I use

```
window.location = '/home.html'
```

for redirecting from index.html to home.html. Home.html has 5 list item menu options. However, clicking one specific list item menu displays index.html for a brief amount of time (which it should not be doing).

Here is the authentication JavaScript code.

```
function google_login_in(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); 
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode     = error.code;
        var errorMessage  = error.message;
        var email         = error.email;
        var credential    = error.credential;
    });         
}

function print_user(user) {
    user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
        console.log("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId);
        console.log("  Provider-specific UID: "+profile.uid);
        console.log("  Name: "+profile.displayName);
        console.log("  Email: "+profile.email);
        console.log("  Photo URL: "+profile.photoURL);
    });
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        print_user(user);
        window.location = '/home.html'
    } else {
        google_login_in();
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<li><a class="Baskets" href="#Baskets" onClick="document.getElementById('BasketsContent')
.style.display='block';document.getElementById('CalendarContent')
.style.display='none';document.getElementById('BrowserContent')
.style.display='none';document.getElementById('AnalyticsContent')
.style.display='none';document.getElementById('SettingsContent')
.style.display='none';document.getElementById('UpgradeContent')
.style.display='none';document.getElementById('ShareContent')
.style.display='none';">
<img class="icon1" src="./images/basket.png">
<i class="baskets"></i>Baskets</a>
</li>
```

Comment: can you add  the click event of the menu list?

Comment: @SuvethanNantha added the click event code

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.href`, this will help you to navigate to the file

for example

```
window.location.href = 'home.html'
```